# time.perf_counter() or time.process_time() for performance measurements?

Tags: python

I understand that time.perf_counter() measures the total time elapsed, even while the process is currently not running. time.process_time() however only measures the time the process is actually running.

If I am just measuring the performance of a function, which of these two is preferred?

Since I am not actually interested in the time my CPU spends tending to other processes, I naturally thought time.process_time() would be the better (and more stable across different runs?) choice, but the name time.perf_counter() seems to suggest otherwise.

**Code Example**

```
import time
from tqdm import trange

start_time_proc = time.process_time()
start_time_perf = time.perf_counter()

tmp = False
for _ in trange(10_000_000):
    tmp = not tmp

elapsed_time_proc = time.process_time() - start_time_proc
elapsed_time_perf = time.perf_counter() - start_time_perf

print("process_time:", elapsed_time_proc)
print("perf_counter:", elapsed_time_perf)
```

https://repl.it/repls/GigaSpryScientists#main.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to measure is to use perf counter and repeat the measurement a couple of times.

Process time is not ofently used and I can easily show you why: `time.sleep(1)` will take 0 seconds according to process time. Every time the process is removed from the scheduler, even if it's due to the code being tested, the process clock won't advance.

May I suggest you to take a look at the built-in timeit module? It uses perf counter as well, and may provide a more comfortable interface for repeated timing.

**Edit**:

If and only if, your function is entirely CPU bound, does not access external resources, nor cause any system call whatsoever, `process_time` is the more accurate and better choice.

Comment: it depends what the measurement goal is: if one wants to measure the real-world elapsed time, like a stopwatch, then indeed you want to include sleep-times and so forth - you want to know how long it takes to go from state A to B. In actual performance benchmarks, we purposefully exclude sleep-time and OS-scheduling artifacts. (a) if your program doesn't perform a calculation, it doesn't contribute to the runtime of the program and (b) the `sleep` time can exceed compute when working on clusters & cloud computers - the program only runs for a time fraction, sharing CPU with other users

Comment: You're completely right, but if your function contains anything that pertains to the OS, and counts on the OS to de-schedule the process, your measurements won't be accurate in process time. It will be accurate for the purpose of calculating the CPU time it costs on the cluster, but if your question is "How long, on average, function x takes to run?", process time does not answer that question.

Comment: If, for example, your function tries to take a mutex, or waits for an event until a timeout of 2 seconds happens. Whats the maximum duration that this function would take? The obvious answer one would expect is 2 seconds + rest of t + dt (for accuracy in scheduling), while on process time the best, average, and worst time would all be "rest of t" albeit with less deviation.

Comment: well, on the first comment you have a point, and the second one doesn't apply (as that suggests something like 'timing asynchronous events' - weird term to use 'timing' or 'benchmarking' here). Indeed, there are artefacts from cluster-related schedulers like SLURM and SGE in that setup, but the definition stands: `process_time` counts the time that passed between 2 timing-calls for that process where the process was not in `sleep()`. Sure, OS's are different, but on linux, the scheduling is an externally-enforced `sleep` event on your process. Thus, `process_time` gets rid of some artefacts.

Comment: The general agreement is to minimize scheduler artefact influence on benchmarks by applying the 'rule of large numbers' and run the benchmarked function several times over, and average the result. Also measuring small sections is more robust to those artefacts that measuring long sections. Still, `process_time` reduces those artefacts already: write a small script with your function, spawn 200 competing processes that just number-count a variable, start the processes, run your function, and time the execution with both modules. Then you see the difference.