# From set and dictionary, which is more efficient to find the first duplicate in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, set

I have to find the first duplicate element in a list. Suppose I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 9]`. The first duplicate here is **3** because when we traverse it from **left to right**, the **2nd 3** comes first before **2nd 1** and **2**.

For solving this problem I have two solutions.

***Using set***

```
def firstDuplicateValue(array):
    duplicate = set()
    for value in array:
        if value in duplicate:
            return value
        else:
            duplicate.add(value)
    return -1
```

***Using dictionary***

```
def firstDuplicateValue(array):
    duplicate = {}
    for value in array:
        if value in duplicate:
            return value
        else:
            duplicate[value] = True
    return -1
```

Which one is more time efficient in python and why? Is there any other best solution?

Comment: set and dict are unordered so how will you find the first?

Comment: why is one not the first?

Comment: the provided list is not unordered. I was provided a list which is ordered. I use set and dictionary to check the current value is already exist or not. If yes, then I returned the value.

Comment: @mama Dicts aren't unordered. And their order doesn't matter here.

Comment: @Shakhawat95 Measure them?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`; who cares a lot about performance in this case, anyway.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Apparently at least *they* do (and me, too). Though I'd like to see your `Counter` solution (admittedly only to point out that it's wrong :-P).

Comment: Dictionaries are used to store key:value pairs, which you don't need here, so in this case the set solutions seems preferable

Comment: Note that both `in` test for set and dict are constant time O(1), but why store a value if you're only interested in the key?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Perhaps because it's faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy But this is exactly what sets are  *meant* for and of course they are highly optimised data structures (once upon a time python actually implemented sets like dict, but no longer)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I agree that "intellectually", a set is the proper data structure for this purpose. Doesn't change the fact that loading and calling a method can easily be slower than the dict's STORE_SUBSCR, for which there is no set equivalent.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Ha... I *finally* found something that might be slightly faster, and it involves... a Counter :-) (but probably not in the way you had in mind, which I still suspect wouldn't work correctly)

Answer (score 1):

In a discussion which can be found in the comments, someone correctly pointed out that the time- and memory-efficiency of the above approaches change with the size of the array to be looked up.

Both Set and Dictionary use a colelction of unique keys, so having similar logic, looking up these keys should have O(n) complexity and you they should not take significantly different timex. The code below, tests these using a list of integers 0, 1, 2, ... and another 0 at the end. Also, note that in the comments below, some have suggested other (perhaps better) approaches to time the processes.

```
import time
import sys

def firstDuplicateValueSet(array):
    duplicate = set()
    for value in array:
        if value in duplicate:
            print(sys.getsizeof(duplicate)/1024)
            return value
        else:
            duplicate.add(value)
    return -1

def firstDuplicateValueDict(array):
    duplicate = {}
    for value in array:
        if value in duplicate:
            print(sys.getsizeof(duplicate)/1024)
            return value
        else:
            duplicate[value] = True
    return -1

size = 50000000
arr = [i for i in range(size)]
arr.append(0)

tic = time.time()
firstDuplicateValueSet(arr)
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic)
tic = time.time()
firstDuplicateValueDict(arr)
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic)
tic = time.time()
```

Memory and time for firstDuplicateValueSet():

```
>>> 2097152.21875
>>> 8.740191221237183
```

Memory and time for firstDuplicateValueDict():

```
>>> 2621440.1015625
>>> 9.246715545654297
```

Setting `size` to `81000000` results in the opposite results. Less time for Dictionary and more memory for Set!

```
>>> 4194304.21875 #set memory
>>> 15.37313985824585 #set time
>>> 2621440.1015625 #dictionary memory
>>> 11.566540002822876 #dictionary time
```

Comment: [I'd also recommend using `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` instead of `time.time()` for performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759802/time-perf-counter-or-time-process-time-for-performance-measurements)

Comment: @PeptideWitch better still the `timeit` module

Comment: I tried size 2650000 instead of your gigantic 1000000000, and the set size gets reported as 131072 while the dict size gets reported as 81920. Also, I ran it multiple times and the dict is consistently significantly faster. So both your claims seem to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the critique btw, just trying to help. I never said it is a list. I used an array and both functions are reading the array in the same way.

Comment: Which one is more efficient (both time and space) depends on the exact size. They leapfrog. And it's not at all expected that set is faster, as loading and calling a method can easily be slower than a STORE_SUBSCR.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right about that. It is not really expected for sets to be faster, since they both use collection of unique keys. I was quick to jump to that conclusion, but a Dictionary with values for each key is expected to take up more room in the memory. Storing those values may cause the slight increase in runtime for large arrays to look up.

Comment: What times/sizes do you get when you change your 50 million to let's say 81 million?

Comment: Weirdly enough I'm getting slightly less time for Dict and more space for Set although this was consistently the other way around for 50 mil size. Thanks for making me repeating the experiment. I'm deleting the answer.

Comment: Yes, with 50 mil, set appears to be better, while with 81 mil, dict appears to be better. And at some larger size, set will likely become better again, and at some even larger size, it'll be dict again. And so on. Like I said, they leapfrog and it depends on the exact size. Though I guess one is better than the other "on average", but I don't think it's obvious which one (or how to define "average" in the first place :-)

Comment: If you use a Python list and Python ints instead of a NumPy array and NumPy ints, you'll likely see times around twice as fast. Not only would that save time for testing, but this extra time (and its variation) of handling NumPy data somewhat masks what you actually want to measure. (Plus the question uses Python data types, so that would be more appropriate anyway.)